# Selecting the last instance of the record but returning the first instance of it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that consist logs of calls.

```
callid  calling_pty dialed_num   disposition    dispvdn   segment     ucid
3862073 25555366    1001              1          1001        1  10000080561437527378
3862073 291113      1015              2          1015        2  10000080621437527416
3862074 635444419   1001              3          1001        1  10000081311437527892
3862075 25555596    1001              1          1001        1  10000081211437527803
3862075 26669       1014              3          1014        2  10000081231437527820
3862076 23044442    1009              2          1009        1  10000080961437527654
3862079 632444419   1001              1          1001        1  10000081361437527904
3862089 0111808     1001              1          1001        1  10000081671437528068
3862091 02366674    1001              1          1001        1  10000081011437527679
3862091 26666       1015              2          1015        2  10000081091437527712
3862097 63255529    1001              1          1001        1  10000081721437528139
3862097 29111       1014              3          1014        2  10000081771437528168
```

Given the sample data, I need to select the records with disposition = 3, but I need to check first if it has an earlier segment [disposition is the status of the call, 3 for abandon and segment is the number of call instances if it is transferred or not in one transaction]. and return the calling_pty(caller number) of the first instance, *hence if there is none, it will return the number of that record.* And it can be identifiend with the help of the callid

So with the given sample,

```
3862075 25555596    1001              1          1001        1  10000081211437527803
3862075 26669       1014              3          1014        2  10000081231437527820
```

it will return to me "25555596", they have the same callid but different calling party which would mean the call was transferred and then it was abandoned.

Therefore: the resulting record should be the "25555596" record.
*This would apply to all records of the same conditions and it will be populated as a list

```
3862074 635444419   1001              3          1001        1  10000081311437527892
3862075 25555596    1001              1          1001        1  10000081211437527803
3862097 63255529    1001              1          1001        1  10000081721437528139
```

*this will be the end result for the sample data

I did a nested select but im on the dead end of how I will check for the first instance. is there a sql function to achieve this?

Comment: At the very least post the desired result based on your sample data with sufficient explanation.

Comment: I did just edited it, thank you!

Comment: I'm confused. Have you provided the **complete** result given your sample data?

Comment: Why is `3862097` not included in your result?

Comment: May I know which part you find it confusing so I could fix it.

Comment: You have **three** rows with `disposition` **3**, but only **two** rows in the resulting table.  This is my current confusion.

Comment: that is just a sample of my desired data, all of the records that will fall to That condition is necessary

Comment: Please provide the **exact** result you expect your query to return based on the sample data.  If you do not like your sample data, edit it first.

Comment: Can you have  dispositions `2` and `3` but no `1`?

Comment: Disposition `3` only. but I need to check first if it has an earlier segment. if there is, that will be the record I will return

Comment: I think I understand now. So you will take all the field values from a record with "`3`" and only `calling_pty` needs to be replaced with the one stored in a record with minimum `segment` value. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If nobody else answers I  will try to post my version late tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two correlated sub-queries:

```
SELECT callid, 
       (SELECT calling_pty 
        FROM Log l
        WHERE Log.callid = l.callid AND
              segment = (SELECT MIN(segment) 
                         FROM Log l2
                         WHERE l.callid = l2.callid) 
       )[calling_pty], 
       dialed_num, disposition, dispvdn, segment, ucid
FROM Log
WHERE disposition = 3
```

[SQL Fiddle **Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa5d0/1)

Comment: Worked like a charm! My sincerest gratitude to you sir!